# Resolve infinite loop issue for jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery

I have following code working to display the list of options inside a textarea when user hits ctrl-enter key.

```
$("#textarea").autocomplete({
 source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"],
 minLength: 0
});

$('#textarea').keydown(function (e) {
if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == 13)) {
   $("#textarea").autocomplete("search","");
}
});
```

It works fne. The issue is sometimes when I hit ctrl-enter,the browser hangs for a some time and then I get a dialog box that asks me if I want to stop or continue the script. The message in the dialog box says

"A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: "location1/codemirror/js/codemirror.js:958" "

In the above message,codemirror.js is another library I am using.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Don't CodeMirror-ize that text area.

Comment: @apsillers That's why I was expressing my concern / question.  Thank you for answering it.

Comment: you are right but I have to Codemirror-ize it since thats the requirement.

Comment: Please let me know some alternative to autocomplete